# Sub-algebra generating a $\sigma$-algebra is dense in this latter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ be a measured set with $\mu$ a probability measure.
Using $1$ as the indicator function we define a distance
$$ d(A,B) = \int_\Omega{|1_A - 1_B | d\mu} ~~ , ~~ A,B\in\mathscr{F}.$$

I wanted to know if we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ which generates $\mathscr{F}$ then $\mathscr{A}$ is dense in $\mathscr{F}$ according to $d$.
I thought it would be useful to show that the set $\{ F \in \mathscr{F} | \forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists A \in \mathscr{A}, d(A,B) < \varepsilon \}$ is equal to $\mathscr{F}$.
One way is obvious.
The other one I don't see what to do. Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

$d$ is not a metric. Indeed, take $\Omega =\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mu\{1\}=\mu\{2\}=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $d(\{3\},\{4\})=0$ but $\{3\}\neq \{4\}$.